# Are all finite languages context-free?

Tags: context-free

As far as I know, finite languages have a finite number of strings or words, while context-free languages are generated by context-free grammars. I don't know which aspect should I know that they are correlated with. All I know is that finite languages are regular, and regular languages are context-free. How should I know this?

Comment: "All I know is that finite languages are regular, and regular languages are context-free." This immediately implies that all finite languages are context-free.

Answer (score 17):

The language consisting of the words $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ is generated by the context-free grammar
$$
S \to w_1 \mid w_2 \mid \cdots \mid w_n.
$$

Comment: So, are all finite languages context-free sir? or just some?

Comment: @JorelleTuyor What this answer is telling you: Every finite language is regular, because it can be created with a regular grammar like above, where the words are simply exhaustively listed. So yes, every finite language is regular (and thus also context free).

Comment: @kutschkem Thank you for clarifying sir. God bless.

Answer (score 1):

Let

- $F$ be the set of finite languages
- $R$ be the set of regular languages
- $C$ be the set of context-free languages.

The statement "All finite languages are regular" can be rewritten $F \subseteq R$.
Similarly, "All regular languages are context-free" can be rewritten $R \subseteq C$. Both being true, we can take $F \subseteq R \land R \subseteq C$ to be true as well.

Set inclusion is known to be a transitive relation, that is $F \subseteq R \land R \subseteq C \rightarrow F \subseteq C$. Thus, by [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens), we can conclude that $F \subseteq C$ is true, or that all finite languages are context-free.

Comment: Very Well said Sir. Thanks.❤